# Logica APP - Paramterize values for getting files from sharepoint and move to blob

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

We are working on a solution of downloading the file posted in share point and movig it to diffrent blob
based on the clinet: xyz,dtf

And her we have same URL below example:

https://ABC.sharepoint.com/teams/ODS/XYZ_Backup/

https://ABC.sharepoint.com/teams/ODS/dtf_Backup/

can we change the folder id and coresponding folder path of blob on fly ,that is parameterize these values for each client something like a lookup table

Also is it possible to change the file name before downloading or after adding a date to it.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do this, why not store the values in a no sql table as key value pairs (Storage table) else use cosmos db. Based on these values you should be able t set the dynamic content on each of the fields required by the connectors

Comment: hi team any update on this

Comment: What @MandarDharmadhikari has mentioned is correct, you should be able to use an external lookup and achieve what you are aiming for.